# How to hide buttons if no room like in actionbar

Tags: android, button, gmail

How to hide buttons if no room like in actionbar or gmail application?

[image]

Comment: put some more information...

Comment: I have 3 buttons in layout like in gmail application, when there is no room for all 3 buttons I need to autohide some buttons like it dooing gmail application or actionbar.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` for your items defined in the menu xml
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html

Comment: I need this for a group of buttons in the layout, not for actionbar.

Answer (score 0):

Add button on Scrollview make it visible or invisible on click of any button which gives information about  when there is no room